# Strange behavior on Android Checkbox with MvvmCross

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have an `MvxListView` defined this way:

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
                        android:background="@drawable/back"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="175dp"
                        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Tipos"
                        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/checkboxcaptionvalue" />
```

The **@layout/checkboxcaptionvalue** is a simple template that has only a checkbox with some bindings:

```
<CheckBox
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto/Capta.Mobile.Vendas"
    local:MvxBind="Checked Selected; Text Caption"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The `Tipos` property is an array of `DummyBool`:

```
private DummyBool[] _tipos;
public DummyBool[] Tipos
{
    get { return _tipos; }
    set { _tipos = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
}
```

And that's the `DummyBool` class:

```
public class DummyBool
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    private bool _selected;

    public bool Selected
    {
        get { return _selected; }
        set { _selected = value; }
    }

}
```

I'm facing a very strange issue: every time I set the `Tipos` property, the `Selected` property of it's itens change to **false**.

I've tried to remove the `RaisePropertyChanged()` from the set of the `Tipos` property, and this way, the `Selected` property does not change, but also my UI is not updated, so I can't see the checkboxes inside the `MvxListView`. I also created a `Button` that has it's **click** binded to the following command:

```
public IMvxCommand RaiseTiposChanged
{
    get
    {
        return new MvxCommand(() =>
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Tipos);
        });
    }
}
```

Calling it also sets the `Selected` property to **false**.

**Edit:**

I'm setting the `Tipos` property this way:

```
Tipos = _pendencias.GroupBy(p => p.Tipo)
                      .Select(g => new DummyBool { Caption = g.Key, Selected = true })
                      .ToArray();
```

`_pendencias` is a simple `List<T>`.

Comment: how are you setting ?

Comment: Please see my edit. Thanks.

Comment: I think `DummyBool` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so changes can be notified to the view

Comment: I tried to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but I still got the same problems. The `Selected` is changed to false if I call the `RaisePropertyChanged` on the `Tipos` property, and if I don't, my `MvxListView` does not update on the UI, so I can't see it's itens.

Comment: I would try to make Tipos a ObservableCollection<DummyBool> and instead of changing the whole collection I would only remove and add the items which should be added or removed.

Comment: I tried to use a `ObservableCollection<DummyBool>` instead of a the `DummyBool[]`, but still got the same problems. I've already done a workaround to this, but I'll leave the question open in case someone find a solution to this.